# How do I use console.log, console.warn, etc in chromium developer console?

Tags: javascript, chromium

Whenever I type console.log, console.warn, console.error in the developers console for Chromium, it doesn't actually print anything. How do I use console.log() in Chromium developer console?

When I type console.log, it does however increment the number of "hidden" messages in the top right hand corner of the console. I can also see that I have logged those messages in the console sidebar, but clicking on the various section in the console sidebar does nothing and clicking on the "hidden" text also does nothing.

This seems like it is intended behavior, but I have chromium set up to view all log levels, so I should be seeing it right?

console.log, warn, and error, all work as expected in Firefox and Chrome however, so is this a bug for Chromium?

Comment: can you give a better example of what is happening and post some example code?
console.log() is working just fine on my end while using chromium. example: console.log('hello')
prints: hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you don't have a filter and you have activated the appropriate log level.

[image: log level]

Comment: I had all of them checked for my log level but I had written something in the filter thinking that it was the find function and then I forgot about it... Thanks! I feel dumb now.